# Identify if multiple UL lists have identical LI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple html lists (UL). Each of these lists have the same number of LI rows.
I am trying to find if both have LI which share the same class, and target these.

For example - the code below have the same LI for the data-attr 'fax', but do not share the same for the data-attr 'email'. I am trying to target the LI with the fax attribute only.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="person-list">
    
      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 value" data-attr="business">      
          <div class="details">
            <strong>John Citizen</strong>
          </div>     
      </li>
      
      <li class="fax col-lg-6 col-sm-12 value empty" data-attr="fax"></li>
      
      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 value" data-attr="phone">
                 <div class="details">
            <a href="tel:123456">123456</a>
          </div>       
      </li>
      
      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 email value empty" data-attr="email"></li>
      
      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 value" data-attr="location">        
          <div class="details">
            Building address here
          </div>       
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <ul class="person-list">
    
      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 value" data-attr="business">       
          <div class="details">
            <strong>John Citizen</strong>
          </div>        
      </li>
      
      <li class="fax value empty" data-attr="fax"></li>
      
      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 value" data-attr="phone">      
          <div class="details">
            <a href="tel:987654">987654</a>
          </div>        
      </li>

      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 email value" data-attr="email">       
          <div class="details">
            <a href="mailto:name@empty.com">name@empty.com</a>
          </div>       
      </li>

      <li class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 value" data-attr="location">       
          <div class="details">
            Building address here
          </div>       
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The approach I am using is to use a simple if/else statement. However I am getting 'false' where I should be getting 'true', and vice versa.

```
// This should return true, as both fax are the same
if($('.fax .value.empty').length === $('.fax .value').length){
    //return true
  console.log('true');
}
else{
    //return false
  console.log('false');
}

// This should return false, as the LI for email are different
if($('.email .value.empty').length === $('.email .value').length){
    //return true
  console.log('true');
}
else{
    //return false
  console.log('false');
}
```

I have created a JSFiddle, as I probably havent articulated the problem very well.
https://jsfiddle.net/r6u39cny/1/

Muchly appreciated and thank you in advance for any suggestions/guidance for solving this problem.

Comment: try `if($('.fax.value.empty').length === $('.fax.value').length){` and `if($('.email.value.empty').length === $('.email.value').length){`

Comment: Thank you @GrafiCode. Fresh perspective really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GrafiCode for picking up the spacing. The solution is below:

```
// This should return true, as both fax are the same
if($('.fax.value.empty').length === $('.fax.value').length){
    //return true
  console.log('true');
}
else{
    //return false
  console.log('false');
}

// This should return false, as both email are different
if($('.email.value.empty').length === $('.email.value').length){
    //return true
  console.log('true');
}
else{
    //return false
  console.log('false');
}
```